# Where's my space?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage

So `df` is telling me that I'm using 49/59G, so I set out to find my space.

```
$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        59G   49G  7.9G  86% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  340K  396M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow        1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp
```

```
I first tried `du`

```
5.1G    .
2.3G    ./var
1.3G    ./usr
973M    ./var/log
834M    ./lib
736M    ./lib/modules
713M    ./var/lib
600M    ./root
592M    ./var/log/nginx
456M    ./var/www
```

Now, I'm no math major, but I'm pretty sure that's not 49G.

I tried `ncdu`, and that's telling i'm using 5GB / 128GB

Comment: Can you run `du --apparent-size` for us? ("although the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like")

Comment: `129T .
128T ./proc
2.3G ./var
1.1G ./usr
980M ./var/log
800M ./lib
704M ./lib/modules
703M ./var/lib
599M ./root
595M ./var/log/nginx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One cause for this is having files that have been deleted from disk, but are still open in memory. These files although deleted, still report as space taken up on the disk.

You can check if you have any files in this state (and also which process is holding them open) with `lsof`.

```
$ lsof | grep deleted

open.pl 15220 steve 3r REG 8,1 70 56099817 /home/steve/scratch/in.txt (deleted)
```

The 7th column (70 in the above case) is the size of the file in bytes. The first column (open.pl) is the process that's holding the file open. The PID of the process is the second column.

Typically this happens when huge log files are removed, but the process that was using them was not restarted.

To free this space, simply restart the service that is still holding the file(s) open.

Comment: I think we have winner....I see all my big logs files in there....

Comment: Simply restart those services and that disk space will be returned (although not always instantaneously).

Comment: Restarted the service didn't help, but I was able to truncate the file as per this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68532/96635

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

There are always a bit "missing"... First of all, the inode-tables, filename-lists in directories and stuff like that will take a bit of space.  I remember old floppys - they were 1.44MB, but with a MS-DOS FAT filesystem, they could only hold 1.38MB.

Second, Linux/Unix-filesystem usually reserve a few percent of the space for root.  This way, if the users fill-up the whole filesystem, there are still room for root to maneuver - and logs belonging to root to be used.  The default is 5% - which on a disk of a terabyte or two, becomes quite a bit (it's safe to reduce it some).

The `tune2fs`command let you specify the percentage with the -m option -- `tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sda1` reserves just 1% (you should keep that much).