# How to find the files that fill my disk

Tags: disk-usage

I have a problem that my disk is filling up but I cant find the files that fill it.
When I run `df -h` I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        53G   51G  2.0G  97% /
devtmpfs        2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
none            395M  204K  395M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

I cleared all caches, logs and auto remove files. When I read this command `du -h /var | sort -nr | head -n 10`
I get:

```
1016K   /var/www/soFit/cache/class_folder-242/soinfitcom/cl
1016K   /var/www/landing/PHPMailer/vendor
1008K   /var/www/dating/libs/vendor
988K    /var/www/libs/mPDF/ttfontdata
968K    /var/www/landing/PHPMailer/vendor/phpmailer
964K    /var/www/landing/PHPMailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer
960K    /var/www/soFitTest/groupChats/vendor/symfony/http-foundation
960K    /var/www/soFitTest/chat/vendor/symfony/http-foundation
960K    /var/www/soFit/groupChats/vendor/symfony/http-foundation
960K    /var/www/soFit/chat/vendor/symfony/http-foundation
```

Using `du -x / | sort -rn | head -n 10`

```
2471828 /
1592004 /var
1091532 /var/lib
929776  /var/lib/mysql
776620  /usr
715092  /var/lib/mysql/soFit
306064  /var/www
291376  /usr/lib
269176  /usr/share
180868  /var/www/libs
```

My mysql db size is ~500MB, not that big.

Where is all the 51G of space are gone to?

My linux is:
 Debian GNU/Linux 7.11 (wheezy)

```
du -h --max-depth=1 /
4.0K    /dev
6.4M    /etc
4.0K    /mnt
759M    /usr
4.0K    /selinux
5.5M    /root
20K     /home
24K     /srv
4.0K    /opt
0       /sys
8.0K    /tigo
8.0K    /media
16K     /lost+found
1.6G    /var
6.5M    /sbin
4.0K    /lib64
7.0M    /bin
4.0K    /.ssh
204K    /run
15M     /lib
4.0K    /boot
12K     /tmp
du: cannot access `/proc/4557/task/19375/fdinfo/312': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/13067/task/13067/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/13067/task/13067/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/13067/fd/5': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/13067/fdinfo/5': No such file or directory
0       /proc
61M     /backups
```

2.4G    /

The answer was to find the files using: `lsof | grep -i deleted` and to delete this files.

Shutdown the machine completely  not only reboot

var/libs/mysql delete (none).log

Comment: Which linux are you using?

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 7.11 (wheezy)

Comment: Why are you only running `du` in `/var`?

Comment: Ok, what other commands should I run?

Comment: No other commands, just use `/` as an argument to `du`. I.e. use something like `du -xh / | sort...` - The `| sort...` looks alright, but personally I prefer using `--max-depth=1` and then repeating in the biggest directory, like @Yaron suggests in his answer.

Comment: I edited the post, still the files are small

Comment: Are you running `du` as root? I simply dont believe that to be the biggest directories on your disc - and du typically also reports the parent directories, so even if your output is correct it should start with `/var` or `/usr` (or some other top level directory).

Comment: Yes, I run as root

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58784/discussion-between-henrik-and-dasdasd).

Comment: A problem was mixing `du`'s `-h` (that uses suffixes) and `sort`'s `-n` (that ignores them).

Answer (score 2):

There may be processes which keep large files open that were already deleted. You can find such open files with `lsof`, or you could just reboot the machine if that is feasible (i.e. if it's not a server that needs to stay up).
See [Find and remove large files that are open but have been deleted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68523)
(Sorry, typing on my phone, so copy/paste is not really comfortable)

Comment: How I find this deleted files?

Comment: Added a link to a previous question on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `du -h` with the `--max-depth` parameter which will get the summary of the folders in the depth you defined, e.g. for depth of 2 folders you can use:

```
du -h --max-depth=2 /
```

Once you'll find which folders holds most of the Data (hint - the size will be in G) you can execute the same command on those folders:

```
du -h --max-depth=2 /folder/which/holds/GB/OF/DATA
```

Note: There some graphical tools which can help (depend on the Linux you are using)

[how-to-analyze-your-disk-usage-pattern-in-linux](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-analyze-your-disk-usage-pattern-in-linux/) holds links to some Linux GUI utils

Comment: I run this command, no big files found.

Comment: btw I connect my server with ssh, no GUI.

Comment: @dasdasd - okay, the method I suggested in my answer should work without GUI

Comment: I run this command and I could not find big files, I also increased the depth and could not see it

Comment: @dasdasd - you should find large folder. and then dig in that folder. did you find large folders (with GB) when running `du -h --max-depth=1 /` ? what did you find when you enter into those folders and execute `du -h /foldername--max-depth=1 /`?

Comment: See my edit for the result

Comment: @dasdasd - please add the result of `df -h /` - it is strange that du -h report about 2GB , and df -h report about 50GB

Comment: See my edit, I found the problem

Comment: Please don't add the solution as an edit to your answer; instead, post an answer and mark it as "best answer" for future readers.