# Not enough disk space to install lsof, which I need to discover which process to kill to free up my disk

Tags: centos

Had a runaway log file that filled up my disk space. I was able to identify and delete it, but it would seem that it is still in use somewhere as `df -h` shows my disk as 160G/160G used even though the file I deleted was 146G. [This issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68523/find-and-remove-large-files-that-are-open-but-have-been-deleted) and other solutions advise using `lsof`, but that isn't present on my system. Running `yum install lsof` (running CentOS 7) fails due to not having enough disk space.

Any suggestions on how to free up this phantom disk space?

Comment: rebooting will kill the process (and finish deleting the file).  you can probably install lsof before it fills up again :-)

Comment: @ThomasDickey thanks for the suggestion but I've actually already restarted the server a handful of times. Figured that would do the trick but it doesn't seem to have. Been using `/sbin/shutdown -r now` -- should I be using something else?

Comment: You can see the open files using `sudo ls -l /proc/*/fd | less`

Comment: If you've rebooted and the disk space is still not freed, check `/lost+found` and, if it's not there, you might need to `fsck`.

Comment: If the  `fuser` command is available, it can be used to see open files.

Comment: @DopeGhoti In my case, disk space is still full after reboot and the /lost+found file is exists. It says a folder taking 20GB space but there is no file in it, I've deleted a big log file from that folder before, what can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ugh, turns out a *different* file had generated after I'd deleted the initial one and I just missed it. Deleted that one and things seem to be back running. Great suggestions in the comments above, though!

@gullum's suggestion of `sudo ls -l /proc/*/fd | less` did essentially what I was looking to do with `lsof`.