# How can my 6 TB hdd display as full while there's 3,4 TB of files on there?

Tags: disk-usage

How can my 6 TB hdd display as full while there's 3,4 TB of files on there? It says 0 bytes available for some reason.

[image]

Comment: Or [Find and remove large files that are open but have been deleted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68523/100397)

Answer (score 0):

*Baobab*, the application you have screenshot,
shows *where **used space** comes from*, that's *which files fill the filled space*;
it does not show you free space.

If you want to see free space (or just as *acid test*) use `df` command or `System Monitor` GNOME utility