# Linux server dev/sda1 full according to df-command, but no files that explain this. What can be done?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, storage

My Linux Ubuntu server stopped working properly after I left a Docker container process working. The server storage is now, according to the result from running "df", completely full. There is, however, only ~36GB of files, and a very small amount of installed programs (this is a virtual server that I started using yesterday). I've killed all running processes, I used "Docker system prune" to tidy out anything related to docker processes, but the result from df still looks like this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  8.9M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       150G  150G     0 100% /
tmpfs           7.7G   28K  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda15      253M  142K  252M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

What could I possible try in order to clear out whatever that Docker process stored somewhere out of sight?

Comment: Have you run `du -x /`?

Comment: Do you use the timeshift program? Maybe you have too many backups...

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Tracking down where disk space has gone on Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/125429/100397)

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Understanding where disk space has gone?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/208953/100397)

Comment: Possible duplicate - [missing disk space on server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/714798/100397)

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Disk full but cannot find were is the used space (Ubuntu)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/675288/100397)

Comment: Please take a look through [other questions on this same topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+where+has+my+disk+space+gone) and mark yours as a duplicate if you find a useful answer