# How to list orphaned inodes?

Tags: inode

I have noticed that my hard drive space is being consumed by a long running process, but I was not able to find the file(s) that are consuming the space.

I suspect the files are temporary files, using the open-and-remove technique to orphan the inode(s), so that when the program terminates (gracefully or crash) that the temporary files get cleaned up automatically.  My suspicion is based on exiting a specific application and seeing my hard drive space go from "almost full" 1% available to "mostly empty" 85% available.

Is there a way to get an `ls` of current orphaned inodes of each of my mounted file systems?

In particular, I'd like to know their sizes.  In bytes or blocks, whichever is easiest to retrieve.

Can `lsof` be of use here?  Since I already know the suspect process, or one-or-more of its child processes.

Comment: This Q/A might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68523/find-and-remove-large-files-that-are-open-but-have-been-deleted

Comment: @A.B • thank you! `lsof +L1` did the trick for what I needed for now, and looks like there is more capabilities there for what I'll need next.